# Docker Volumes: Persisting Data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, persistent-volumes

I have a docker-compose file below where I have a mariadb with volume.  Each time i perform a docker-compose pull and docker-compose up -d i lose the data after updating the image

```
mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb-db
    ports:
      - 3303:3306
    environment:
      - "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
      - "MARIADB_EXTRA_FLAGS=--max-connect-errors=1000 --max_connections=300"
      - "MARIADB_DATABASE=mydb"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

How do i make the data persistent?

Comment: Do you use any other commands such as `docker-compose down -v` or  `docker prune`?

Comment: No, only docker-compose pull and docker-compose up and if the image updates, on restarting it, the data is gone.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb#persisting-your-database), the database inside the container is at `/bitnami/mariadb`. This isn't standard, rather a feature of `bitnami/mariadb` image. It would be `/var/lib/mysql` if you had used an [official one](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb).

Thus, either change the path inside the container:

```yaml
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/bitnami/mariadb
```

or use the default path with an official image:

```yaml
    image: mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: in bitnami/mariadb should use /bitnami/mariadb and /var/lib/mysql dow not work.thank you @anemyte